# How can I stop these variables from resetting while still being able to loop them?

Tags: python

Here's part of my code:

```
def dice_game():
     dice_window = Tk()
     dice_window.geometry('450x450')
     player1_score = 0 
     player2_score = 0
     def player1_turn():
         player1_num1 = random.randint(1, 6)
         player1_num2 = random.randint(1, 6)
         player1_score = player1_num1 + player1_num2
         player1_total = player1_num1 + player1_num2
         if (player1_total % 2) == 0:
             player1_score = player1_score + 10
         else:
             player1_score = player1_score - 5
         player1_result = Label(dice_window, text = ( "Player 1 got", player1_num1, "and", player1_num2, "and their total score is:", player1_score))
         player1_result.pack()
     for x in range(1, 6):
         player1_turn()
```

I've tried putting the loop inside the player1_turn () function and in the dice_game() function but the outcome is always the same. How can I keep the 2 players score without resetting them every time this section loops 5 times?

Comment: Look up more information about the scope of a nested function. Then, you have to add to the score, not reinitialize it every time. That will reset the value.

Comment: Make a [MCVE] and [edit] it in to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down. I can see that `player1_turn()` is nested because you want to have access to `dice_window`. But there is a better way!

First separate the functions. `player1_turn` needs a dice window, and it looks like the thing you want to save is `player1_score`, so we'll return that.

```
def player1_turn(dice_window):
    player1_num1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    player1_num2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    player1_score = player1_num1 + player1_num2
    player1_total = player1_num1 + player1_num2
    if (player1_total % 2) == 0:
        player1_score = player1_score + 10
    else:
        player1_score = player1_score - 5
    player1_result = Label(dice_window, text = ( "Player 1 got", player1_num1, "and", player1_num2, "and their total score is:", player1_score))
    player1_result.pack()
    return player1_score
```

Now onto the game:

```
def dice_game():
    dice_window = Tk()
    dice_window.geometry('450x450')

    # we're not using x, so we should make it clear that this is a loop of 5
    scores = []
    total = 0
    for x in range(5):
        player1_score = player1_turn(dice_window)
        # now what to do with the score?
        scores.append(player1_score)  # save it?
        print(player1_score)  # print it?
        total += player1_score  # add it up
    print(scores)
    print(total)
```

Comment: So how should I put this together on my code? Just have them after each other?

Comment: Yep, just one after the other. If "Now onto the game:" was removed from my post.

Comment: It works kind of. I'll tweak it a little but what you've given me has fixed my core problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are assigning `player1_score` and `player2_score` inside the body of  `player1_turn()` function, it makes `player1_score & player2_score` local variable of function `player1_turn()`.

So, if you are using `python3` you can define `player1_score` and `player2_score` as non-local variable explicitly using `nonlocal` keyword.

The code will look like this.

```
def dice_game():
     dice_window = Tk()
     dice_window.geometry('450x450')
     player1_score = 0 
     player2_score = 0
     def player1_turn():
         nonlocal player1_score, player2_score
         player1_num1 = random.randint(1, 6)
         player1_num2 = random.randint(1, 6)
         player1_score = player1_num1 + player1_num2
         player1_total = player1_num1 + player1_num2
         if (player1_total % 2) == 0:
             player1_score = player1_score + 10
         else:
             player1_score = player1_score - 5
         player1_result = Label(dice_window, text = ( "Player 1 got", player1_num1, "and", player1_num2, "and their total score is:", player1_score))
         player1_result.pack()
     for x in range(1, 6):
         player1_turn()

# END
```

For python 2, there is a workaround that you can store the `player1_score & player2_score` in a dict like `score = {'player1_score': 0, 'player2_score': 0}`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code as it is has your for loop inside your dice_game() function.
As you can see you're declaring the scores to zeroes in that function. So, to call the for loop you need to call dice_game(), which resets the scores to zero again.

Maybe you should try taking that for loop outside of the function dice_game(), and in the end, the score will be preserved. Or you can take the declarations

```
player1_score = 0 
player2_score = 0
```

outside the function, as global variables.